# How do I create a padString function in Java?

Tags: java, padding

Every other question I have seen in my book I had at least some understanding of what the book was asking but this one I have no idea on how to approach it. It goes:

"Write a method called **padString** that accepts two parameters: a String and an integer representing a length. For example,

```
padString ("hello", 8)
```

should return `"hello   "` (that's three spaces in there at the end). If the string's length is already at least as long as the length parameter, your method should return the original string. For example,

```
padString ("congratulations", 10)
```

should return `"congratualtions"`.

I have no idea on how to approach this being pretty new to Java. This is supposed to be a beginner's homework so I suppose the method is very simple. Please show me how to do this and explain the steps if you can. Please and Thank you to whoever helps.

Comment: haha, it is Sunday night...  homework question coming in for assignments due on Monday or Tuesday (or Wednesday)

Comment: Can you change your question title to indicate the subject matter?

Comment: What? Your examples don't make sense to me.

Comment: I don't think showing you is the intent of the exercise. At best we should indicate a direction for you to experiment with. To that end, the answer below already gives you a good outline of how you can solve this problem.

Answer (score 4):

So your function should do something like this:

1. Determine number of padding characters required.
2. Need <= 0 padding characters? return input string
3. Otherwise, create a string with required padding characters, then return input string + required padding characters

You can find a string's length with the `.length()` method.

Comment: Slight correction: while arrays have a .length property, Strings have a .length() method. (Which is annoying, since they're both objects.)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `printf` method in `System.out` (needs Java 1.6 or later, it's a new `PrintStream` method). Hake a look at an interesting example below, where the output is (specified below code). The padding is specified in the printf argument as 30, and is justified left:

```
package pft;

public class PrintfTest {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        int padding = 30;
     String s = "hi!";
     System.out.printf("'%0$-" + padding + "s'", s);
 }
}

prints: 'hi!                           '.
```

Comment: +1 for a more production-like example (though it may be too advanced for the lecturer). Why Java didn't see fit to allow the `*` width specifier is still a mystery to me - I don't like all that dynamic creation of format strings stuff.

Comment: And if you had to return a string, you could even use String.format("%" + pad + "s", str) to do the same, which is probably the code I'd use, even on homework :)

Answer (score 1):

Taking it piece at a time (and without giving you all the code):

> "Write a method called padString that
>   accepts two parameters: a String and
>   an integer representing a length."

```
public static ??? padString(String str, int len)
```

> "For example,padString("hello", 8)
>   should return "hello"."

```
public static String padString(String str, int len)
{
    throw new Error("not implemented yet");
}
```

> "If the string's length is already at
>   least as long as the length parameter,
>   your method should return the original
>   string. For example,
>   padString("congratulations", 10)
>   should return "congratualtions"."

EDIT: you fixed the question...

```
public static String padString(String str, int len)
{
    // if the str.length is greater than len
    //     return str

    // this next part is very simple, not a very good way but gets you 
    // started. Once you have it working look at StringBuilder and .append.

    // int val = the difference in length between the two strings

    // for i = 0; i is less than val; i++
    //     str += " ";           

    // return str
}
```

Comment: +1 for explaining the problem and approach yet not giving the code ( As he is working on homework assignment :-D )

Answer (score 1):

```
public class PadString {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "hello";
        str = padStr(str, 10, ' ');
    }

    static String padStr(String s, int len, char c) {

        int n = len - s.length();
        if (n <= 0)
            return s;
        StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder(s);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            b.append(c);
        return b.toString();

    }
}
```

Comment: +1. If would help if you format your code and show another padStr that calls padStr(s, len, ' ');.

Answer (score 1):

Even thought this post is about 2 years old. I just recently had this
 question for a homework. And I thought it might help other beginners
 that might come across this problem to see a simpler way of solving
this problem.

One that will probably be more in line to where they are in their
 beginner java course assuming they are getting this around the same
 time that I did.

Of course you should remove the dashes in the loop and use spaces to
 get credit for the assignment, that is there just to show you that it
 works.

```
public class ex3_11_padString {
          public static void main(String[] args) {

             padString("hello",10);
          }

          public static String padString( String s, int len) {

             int s_length = s.length();
             int diff = len - s_length;
             String newString;

             newString = "";

             for (int x = 0 ; x < diff; x++) {
                newString += "-";
             }

             newString = newString + s;


             return new String;
             }
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at Java's String class documentation. Look for a method that returns the length of the string...

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String padString(String str, int len) 
{ 

int lengt=str.length();
if(lengt==len||lengt>len)
 return str;
else if(lengt<len){
 String spacstr="";
 for(var i=lengt;i<len;i++){
    spacstr+="$";
 }
 return str+spacstr;
}

} 

///more generalized  by accepting pad character



public static String padString(String str, int len,String padChar) 
{ 

int lengt=str.length();
if(lengt==len||lengt>len)
 return str;
else if(lengt<len){
 String spacstr="";
 for(var i=lengt;i<len;i++){
    spacstr+=padChar;
 }
 return str+spacstr;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public String padString (String s, int padding) {

   return String.format("%-" + padding + "s", s);

}
```

This is the better solution for me. Taken from the comment of @John C, with the "%-" added.

Sorry @John C I cannot edit your comment or add one below yours.